# BASH SCRIPT - Change TRUE to FALSE for a Key in an Array

Tags: arrays, bash, boolean, key

I have very basic knowledge of bash scripts but nothing complex. I've been searching/testing for days and can't get the results I need...

I have an Info.plist located in: /Dir1/Dir2

In the Info.plist is an array: CFBundleURLTypes

In that array is a key: CFBundleURLIsPrivate

And that key is: TRUE

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleURLIsPrivate</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

I want to change this value to FALSE but my testing hasn't worked.  Here's what I've tried and if there's a better way to do this, PLEASE let me know! TIA

```
#!/bin/bash
#Access working directory
cd /Dir1/Dir2
sed -i "/<key>CFBundleURLIsPrivate</{n;s/true/false/;}" Info.plist
```

Answer (score 2):

The `sed` pattern should work fine, however, on OS X (which I'll assume you're using) in-place edits have to be done slightly different:

```
sed -i '' "/<key>CFBundleURLIsPrivate</{n;s/true/false/;}" Info.plist
```

If you don't include the `''` then you'll likely get an invalid command error.

Comment: Thanx for the help!  Unfortunately, it throws this error now:

Comment: What is the error, and are you using OS X? please include what was failing to begin with.

Comment: Sorry, my phone screwed up before finishing that post.  I'm using iOS, btw: Thanx for the help!  Unfortunately, it throws this error now -  sed: can't read /<key>CFBundleURLIsPrivate</{n;s/true/false/;}: No such file or directory

Comment: @thazsar: Try using `sed -i -e'/<key>CFBundleURLIsPrivate</{n;s/true/false/;}' Info.plist`

Comment: Well, I don't get any errors but it doesn't change the value to FALSE.  Could it be a permissions problem?

Comment: Yeah I'm thinking it might be a permissions issue; you could always test `sed` without writing to a file by doing: `echo '<true/>' | sed 's/true/false/g` ` to determine if that is at least working. Do you have CLI access on your iOS? (it's unclear if you do or not).

Comment: Here are some other tests you could try: [sed tests (gist)](https://gist.github.com/Ubiquitous/49d44dc21e9be99a54dba5b398b42da8)

Comment: Yes, I have access and running echo finds the key: CFBundleURLIsPrivate.  I changed the permissions (using bash) to 777 but it still doesn't change the value to FALSE.  So confused ATM...

Comment: Well, if it's a permissions issue then you might have to chmod/chown the script and/or the plist (eg. on the script `chmod +x script.sh`, and on the plist you would do `chown <your user>:<your group> Info.plist`). Before you do that though check what the owner:group permissions are for the files.

Comment: I'll test out different ownerships to see if i can get this to take.  If so, i'll let you know.  Thanx!!!  Currently, its set to: root-admin